# If formula with isblank in it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When trying to do a formula, it emits a #Value error.

The formula is currently:

```
=IF(BID!I128>0,IF(ISBLANK(E24),BID!I128,BID!I128-E24-E27),"")
```

that is giving me this error.

In cell E24, the formula is

```
=IF(Labor!K34>0,Labor!K34,"")
```

and same with E27. How do I fix this so that it won't give me a #Value error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM, which ignores text; replace

```
 -E24-E27
```

with

```
 -SUM(E24,E27)
```